# Як краще перекласти слово "Affluenza"

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

В Інтернеті натрапив на статтю "[Affluenza: The Sickness You Don’t Know You Have](https://littlegreenseedling.com/2017/06/21/affluenza/)". Тут мене зацікавило слово "Affluenza", тому вирішив подивитися його переклад, ось що дають різні джерела:

**Гугл Перекладач**:

*Апетит* (але перекладає він з італійської, напевно, в його базі взагалі немає такого слова)

**[Глобс](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/Affluenza)**:

Жодного варіанту.

**Словники на [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=Affluenza&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)**:

Жодного варіанту.

Що ж вазагалі означає це слово? "[Affluenza](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/affluenza)" - слово, яке використовують, щоб описати так звану "хворобу споживання" (affluence — достаток, а іnfluenza — грип). Тобто я здогадуюся, що, швидше за все, такого відповідника просто немає в нашій мові, а тому мені ще більше цікаво як можна перекласти цей термін (бо "хвороба споживання" звучить не дуже добре).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мій варіант - *достагрип*, утворив за прикладом оригіналу від *достаток* і *грип*.

Comment: Дуже цікавий і хороший варіант! Дякую вам!